# zen cart add dimensions to a product

Tags: php, zen-cart

I'm new to Zen cart and am editing an existing shop. I would like to display the dimensions of the products in the cart (ie width, height, length and a couple of product specific dimensions).

I've had a good google and the only methods I can find involve the shipping plugins ozpost (monthly fee I don't want) and Canada Post, but this is for a UK based site and it's nothing to do with shipping, it's just a selling point.

I can't find any plugins to do it, or examples on how to edit the code to add them in. I'd really appreciate any help on this...

Comment: It's probly a matter of editing one of the template files to show a couple more fields from a db hit (may already be accessible to the view layer).  How good are you w/ PHP?  I suspect you might have to edit a query as well if it isn't pulling back all the data you need; not too bad on the whole though.

Comment: I've been doing PHP for years, but I'm not sure how to hook it into Zen cart (on publicand admin levels) and would doing this require editing the core? If so could that prevent me from updating the system?

Comment: no, i don't think you'd need to edit the core really aside from maybe adding a couple fields in an existing query if they're not already in there.  just grep the source for something from the html on the page you want to edit.  that will get you into the view layer file you need to edit.  from there you can see where the data is coming from to populate the html w/ the data from the db.  you can var_dump to see if it has all the fields already.  if it does, simply add the html and plugin the extra fields.  if not, you'll have to dig to the query and tweak it to get the extra fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module that can do what you want: [Numinix Product Fields](http://www.numinix.com/zen-cart-modules/admin/numinix-product-fields)

You'll need to utilize the optional fields, but it's RATHER simple to install and use. And, this module CAN be used for various shipping calculations if supported by the shipping module or you can modify the shipping module to support it.

If you just need to display the dimensions on the frontend and not use it for shipping, this is really straight forward. You'll just need to edit your includes/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/templates/tpl_product_info_display.php and add a line of code to call for the dimensions. If you download the module, you'll find a sample file where you can see the code required. In your case (for dimensions), this would be

```
<?php echo (($flag_show_product_info_dimensions == 1 && ($products_length != 0 || $products_width != 0 || $products_height != 0)) ? '<li>' . $products_dim_display . '</li>'  : '') . "\n"; ?>
```

There's an alternative - you can add additional properties to your products table in the database. You'd need to alter 4 core files, add one function and some language definitions. Keep in mind this is quite delicate and you really need to know what you're doing for this to work so I'm not gonna explain it here. I've done it quite a few times and I still get mistaken sometimes.

Don't forget to BACKUP BACKUP BACKUP! :)